# Naming conventions in JavaScript for functions inside objects?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, capitalization

I would like to be sure I am using the most common naming convention. In the example below would it be more common for `deleteEntity` to be `deleteEntity` or `DeleteEntity`?

```
var factory = {
    deleteEntity: function (entityType, entityId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        EntityResource.deleteEntity({ entityType: entityType, entityId: entityId },
           function (resp) {
               deferred.resolve(resp);
           }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be more common to be lowercase. It would still work, but generally capital Functions are reserved for constructors (i.e. used with the `new` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

There are no set naming conventions that I know of as such. But as a Java developer, I will be  happy to see variables and methods following lower Camel Casing like `deleteEntity`. But Dot net developers may be comfortable with Upper camel casing like "DeleteEntity".

Comment: You could follow the naming convention of the standard library.